# How to delete a full row in a ListView if no items are there?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listview, for-loop

I'm doing something that loads items into two columns in a `ListView`.

Is there a loop I can run so that if a row does not have an item under `column1` AND `column2`, the row is automatically deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var lst = new  ListView();
            for (int i = lst.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var itemtoremove = //Put your condition here and get that item
            lst.Items.Remove(lst.Items.Find("key"));
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by condition? I dont want to delete a row if it says 'soccer' for example, I want to delete a row if any of the two columns don't contain anything.

Comment: Also, I tried the code, and there was this error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem

Comment: ok.. I don't have ide with me..but logically u should remove the items in reverse direction.